# Inserting space between address and cardinal direction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, address, regular-expression

I have a shapefile, which is a parcel map. Its table of contents has a column containing the addresses of several buildings. Some of the addresses hold directional information (i.e. n, s, w, e).

The problem is that there is no space between house numbers and the directional information, which might cause issues later in the project. Below are some examples:

- 100W GERMAN ST
- 100W HIGH ST
- 100W WASHINGTON ST

How can I add a single space, i.e. *100 W* instead of *100W*? I am assuming that this can be done using regular expression, however since I have not faced such an issue before, I am not sure what exactly the regular expression should be.

Comment: So you want 100 W instead of 100W, am I right ?

Comment: Correct. Can that be done using Regex or any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex case assertion is what you need, use this expression in the Field Calculator:

```
regexp_replace("field_name", '(?<=[0-9])(?=[N,W,S,E])', ' ')
```

Replace `field_name` with a field containing the addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
 regexp_replace("fieldname",'(.*\\d)([EWSN])','\\1 \\2')
```

This looks for a number of any length, followed by one of the letters EWSN and introduces a space before E,W,S, or N.